# Android ActivityResult API unresolved reference error registerForActivityResult

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, registerforactivityresult, getcontent

I am trying to use ActivityResult APIs as stated here [ActivityResult APIs](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2020/07/jetpack-activityresult.html)

But it is giving unresolved reference error.

[image]

I am using following dependencies

```
api 'androidx.activity:activity:1.1.0'
api 'androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.1.0'
api 'androidx.fragment:fragment:1.2.5'
api 'androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.2.5'
```

Comment: Have a look at the dependencies listed on your linked page. It doesn't explicitly state so, and I've not checked yet, but those are probably the minimum versions necessary.

Comment: Yes I tried with those mentioned versions also but same error then I thought to use stable versions.

Comment: Yeah, I got the same behavior. Odd. However, my IDE tells me the newest versions are `alpha07`, and it works as expected when upgrading to those. That is, `"androidx.activity:activity:1.2.0-alpha07"` and `"androidx.fragment:fragment:1.3.0-alpha07"`.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

As per the [Getting a result from an activity guide](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result):

> it is strongly recommended to use the Activity Result APIs introduced in AndroidX [Activity 1.2.0-alpha02](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/activity#1.2.0-alpha02) and [Fragment 1.3.0-alpha02](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/fragment#1.3.0-alpha02).

So using the stable versions will not include those APIs. The latest versions of each is alpha07, which would mean your dependencies would be:

```
api 'androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.2.0-alpha07'
api 'androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.3.0-alpha07'
```

NOTE: your activity must extend from `ComponentActivity`, which was introduced in [AppCompat 1.1.0](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/appcompat#1.1.0) and includes the `registerForActivityResult()` API

Comment: I have the same issue and having this didn't help. The IDE shows "Unresolved reference: registerForActivityResult" , yet it can build just fine... How could it be?

Comment: Also unable to get Android Studio to autocomplete `registerForActivityResult`. It's saying "Unresolved reference: registerForActivityResult" so I cannot code with this api at all.

Answer (score 4):

try this one new version is come.

```
 implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.3.1'
```

Comment: I Have this on my build.gradle but I also get the error specified earlier.

Comment: @cyber_angel OK, but please check dependencies of project build.gradle with version of gradle require to latest one to works.

Comment: please check you kotlin version gradle.

Answer (score 3):

Just in case someone else has this problem when working in an old project...

I saw in a different computer using inheritance that your activity extends from `AppCompatActivity()` which extends from `FragmenteActivity()`.

I notice `FragmentActivity` is different from the one were I was having this issue...

So I updated the appcompat library, using :

```
 androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1
```

And this solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you added these dependencies in your build.gradle

```
implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.7.2'
implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.6.0'
```

If it doesn't works then clear your file system cache and local history with `File -> Invalidate Cache & Restart` and rebuild your project.