# How to get Callback share result in android

Tags: java, android, flutter, kotlin

How to get the `intent` callback sharing result, i have seen some code and implemented from my side. Below is the sample code

```
try {
            Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            intent.setType("text/plain");
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Body");
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Choose"), 1);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Code for callback result

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 1) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        }
    }
}
```

In this `requestCode` is always getting `0` not 1 after i successfully share to any social media platform, is there any code which is newer version?

Answer (score 0):

The method you're using is deprecated, The new way is

```
ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> launcher = registerForActivityResult(
    new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(), result -> {
        if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Intent data = result.getData();
            // do something
        }
    });
```

**Launching the activity**

```
launcher.launch(yourIntent);
```

**sharing result**

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtra(YOUR_KEY, YOUR_DATA);
setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
```

**Dependency**

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.2'
    implementation "androidx.activity:activity:1.2.0"
    ...
}
```

*To learn more about this [visit](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result)*

Comment: where do i call this `ActivityResultLauncher`  in MainActivity?

Comment: You don't have to call it just initialize it like a variable [visit](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result) for more details

Comment: It's showing `Unresolved reference: registerForActivityResult`

Comment: @MohammedNabil try _invalidate cache and restart_ or refer to this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63067027/16177121)

Comment: That Doesn't work for me.

Comment: so... why doesn't it work?

Comment: @MohammedNabil  try upgrading `androidx.appcompat` to latest version and check for the dependency mentioned above

Comment: @SidharthMudgil I even added those two dependencies and synced but showing error on `registerForActivityResult`